# LOG4J - Can you direct specific class logging to only one appender exclusively?

Tags: logging, log4j

The com.examples is pouring INFO logs to EXAMPLESAPPENDER.
log4j.logger.com.examples=INFO, EXAMPLESAPPENDER

The com.examples.database is pouring INFO logs to DBAPPENDER.
log4j.logger.com.examples.dblayer=INFO, DBAPPENDER

The com.examples.dblayer INFO logs will pour in both the appenders.

Is there a way to exclusively restrict the com.examples.dblayer package from pouring INFO log entries to anything other than DBAPPENDER?

The requirement is to capture log entries from com.examples.dblayer package only in one of the log files and these must not show up in other log files that are configured to capture parent packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, loggers inherit their appenders from their antecesors. To prevent this behaviour you can add the following line:

```
log4j.additivity.com.examples.dblayer = false
```

This means a log statement of the logger `com.examples.dblayer` will only go to `com.examples.dblayer` appenders. It won't go up to its ancestors appenders.